# ASP.NET windows authentication + ajax= 403 error status code

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, windows-authentication

I am using asp.net windows authentication in my website.
After authenticating, the website functions normally (even ajax requests are authorized).

But after a certain time when I make ajax calls to the server, the server returns 403 status code (unauthorized) .

What is the reason and how can I fix it?

here is the case:

1- first I login with my LDAP credentials

[image]

2- A page containing a button to fetch data with ajax opens

[image]

3-On clicking the button data is fetched.BUT after leaving the website in idle mode for a while without making any request to the server, AJAX calls return 403 status (Forbidden)

[image]

Please note when I redirect to other pages everything is normal. I have no 403 status code returned.

and here is the ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/GetFilteredRecords/', 
        data://filter goes here,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (result) { 
           //display result
        },
        error: function (result) {
           alert("something went wrong");
        }
});
```

Comment: Your authentication token or cookie is expired. You need to refresh it.

Comment: Or; Please [edit] the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer, for example by providing some code or more details on the authentication.

Comment: @Stephan I updated the question for more clarification. Do you still think that the cookie has expired?

Comment: Can you show the script that's making the ajax call?

Comment: @Stefan I added the ajax request at the bottom of the question.What do you think?

Comment: I think that this a tricky question ;-). But, please verify the following: 1) is the ajax call made to the same domain? (it's a requirement for the sliding cookie to be set) 2) is there extensive caching involved? 3) In your case you might want to try the following ajax call option: `xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },`

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior with Windows Authentication. Windows Authentication supports multiple authentication protocols - Kerberos, NTLM, maybe others. Your browser tries one authentication method, and when it fails, it tries another one, until it succeeds. You shouldn't worry about this. As you can see, the second request to the same URL succeeds. You can look at the authentication headers of each request to see what it does exactly.

Comment: Thank you @Tashi Asher . But why the authentication timeout on ajax requests and not on page redirect or refresh? Is there a timeout parameter somewhere that I should change?

Comment: @Fadi.AM I don't know. We saw this too in AJAX calls, but didn't investigate full page requests. We don't worry about this too much.